# Inserting few fields from CSV in SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I have a CSV file from which I want to enter data into a table. It is a big CSV file, containing **300K** records. I read about bulk insert, but here I want to add only some fields using CSV, rest of the fields are constants:

My normal insert is like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table_1
(TYPE,EVENT_ID, BASE_ID ,ID) VALUES 
('NEW',<CSV_FIELD1>, 1, <CSV_FIELD2>)
```

As per this, I want to fetch only second and the last field from the CSV file. How do I do this?

Also, after insertions, I want to verify that all of these records are present in the table or not. I can't simply do `count(*)` as there will some simultaneous insertions in the table. How do I verify using CSV? It is an Oracle DB.

Comment: Extract record from CSV and then insert only desired data into database. All should be done via PL/SQL stored procedure at form level.

Comment: Have you looked at external tables or SQL\*Loader?

Answer (score 1):

What @alex-poole said, SQL*Loader.

SQL Developer will let you:

- map the columns you do want to read in from the CSV
- create a script that will launch SQL*Loader
- create the sql*loader ctl file that maps the cols from the csv to the cols in the table
- after sql*loader is done, rejected (failed) rows are logged to a file

[image: click, click, click...]

You'll need to install an Oracle Client on your machine to be able to run SQL*Loader.

[Using SQL Developer to setup a SQL*Loader Run](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/08/using-oracle-sql-developer-to-setup-sqlloader-runs/)